# Given one solution to $z^6 = z_0$, how do I find the others?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $w \in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution to the equation $z^6 = z_0$, for some fixed $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Find six numbers $\zeta_0, \ldots, \zeta_5 \in \mathbb{C}$ with the property that the set $\{ ζ_0w, ζ_1w, \ldots , ζ_5w \}$ is the set of solutions to $z^6 = z_0$.

I'd really appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  You should indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2):

You get the rest of the solutions by multiplying with a primitive sixth root of unity, i.e.
$$w \cdot e^{2\pi i k/ 6}$$
for $k = 0, \ldots, 5$.